Unable to Access Expo React Native Project URL on googles IDX editor
I’ve set up my React Native project with Expo, but I’m having trouble accessing the project using the provided URL exp://10.88.0.4:8081. how can I access it on my expo go app
i tried to go to the url provied but it didn’t work. i want to access it on my expo go app

npx expo start --tunnel
use the --tunnel flag. It should help expose the URL.
And then click the IDX menu on the left side panel, and on the bottom copy the url that matches the port that the client server is running on.
source : https://community.idx.dev/t/unable-to-access-expo-react-native-project-url/596/3
